# Understanding `bind` of `newtype Prob`

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads) presents the `Prob` newtype:

`newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a,Rational)] } deriving Show`

Here's `Prob`'s definitions:

```
instance Functor Prob where  
    fmap f (Prob xs) = Prob $ map (\(x,p) -> (f x,p)) xs  

instance Monad Prob where
    return x = Prob [(x, 1%1)]
    p >>= f  = flatten (fmap f p)
```

And then the supporting functions:

```
flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a
flatten = Prob . convert . getProb 

convert :: [(Prob a, Rational)] -> [(a, Rational)]
convert = concat . (map f)

f :: (Prob a, Rational) -> [(a, Rational)]
f (p, r) = map (mult r) (getProb p)

mult :: Rational -> (a, Rational) -> (a, Rational)
mult r (x, y) = (x, r*y)
```

I wrote the flatten, convert, f, and mult functions, so I'm comfortable with them.

Then we apply `>>=` to the following example, involving a data type, `Coin`:

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails deriving (Show, Eq)

coin :: Prob Coin 
coin = Prob [(Heads, 1%2), (Tails, 1%2)]

loadedCoin :: Prob Coin
loadedCoin = Prob [(Heads, 1%10), (Tails, 9%10)]
```

LYAH says, `If we throw all the coins at once, what are the odds of all of them landing tails?`

```
flipTwo:: Prob Bool
flipTwo= do
  a <- coin       -- a has type `Coin`
  b <- loadedCoin -- similarly
  return (all (== Tails) [a,b])
```

Calling `flipTwo` returns:

```
Prob {getProb = [(False,1 % 20),(False,9 % 20),(False,1 % 20),(True,9 % 20)]}
```

`flipTwo` can be re-written with `>>=`:

```
flipTwoBind' :: Prob Bool
flipTwoBind' = coin >>= 
                    \x -> loadedCoin   >>= 
                                       \y -> return (all (== Tails) [x,y])
```

I'm not understanding the type of `return (all (== Tails) [x,y])`. Since it's the right-hand side of `>>=`, then its type must be `a -> m b` (where `Monad m`).

My understanding is that `(all (==Tails) [x,y])` returns `True or False`, but how does `return` lead to the above result:

`Prob {getProb = [(False,1 % 20),(False,9 % 20),(False,1 % 20),(True,9 % 20)]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'll call your `coin` `fairCoin`) You have:

```
flipTwoBind' :: Prob Bool
flipTwoBind' = fairCoin     >>=  g   where
   g x       = loadedCoin   >>=  h   where
     h y     = return z              where 
       z     = all (== Tails) [x,y]
```

From the type of `(>>=)` we get:

```
fairCoin ::         Prob Coin
(>>=) :: Monad m => m    a    ->  (a -> m b) -> m b       | m ~ Prob, a ~ Coin
                    fairCoin  >>=    g       :: m b       | g :: Coin -> Prob b
flipTwoBind'                              :: Prob Bool    | m ~ Prob, b ~ Bool
```

so that `g :: Coin -> Prob Bool` and `g x :: Prob Bool` provided that `x :: Coin`.

Since `g x = loadedCoin >>= h`, we have

```
loadedCoin ::       Prob Coin
(>>=) :: Monad m => m    a    ->  (a -> m b) -> m    b 
                  loadedCoin  >>=    h       :: Prob Bool
```

So, `h :: Coin -> Prob Bool`, `z :: Bool` and `return z :: Prob Bool`:

```
all ::  (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all        p           []  :: Bool

return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
z      ::           Bool
return                 z :: m Bool           | m ~ Prob so return z :: Prob Bool
```

Since `Prob a` is essentially a tagged assoc-list of pairs of `a` outcomes and their corresponding probabilities, `Prob Bool` is a list of pairings of `Bool` outcomes and their probabilities.

---

Translated with the specific `Prob` monadic code, inlining all the functions, `flipTwoBind'` becomes

```
flipTwoBind' = fairCoin     >>=  g
   = flatten (fmap g fairCoin)
   = Prob . convert . getProb $ 
             Prob $ map (\(x,p) -> (g x,p)) $ getProb fairCoin
   = Prob . concat . map (\(x,p) -> map (\(x, y) -> (x, p*y)) $ getProb x)
                  . map (\(x,p) -> (g x,p)) $ getProb fairCoin
```

(see how nicely the `Prob` and `getProb` cancel each other there on the inside...).

Switching to plain list-based code (with `gL xs = getProb (g (Prob xs))` and `fairCoinL = getProb fairCoin` etc.), it is equivalent to

```
   = concat . map (\(x,p) -> map (second (p*)) x)
            . map (\(x,p) -> (gL x,p)) $ fairCoinL
   = concat . map (\(x,p) -> map (second (p*)) $ gL x) $ fairCoinL
   = [(v,p*q) | (x,p) <- fairCoinL, (v,q) <- gL x]
   = ....
   = [(z,r)   | (x,p) <- [(Heads,   1%2),  (Tails,   1%2 )],   -- do a <- fairCoin
                (y,q) <- [(Heads, p*1%10), (Tails, p*9%10)],   --    b <- loadedCoin
                (z,r) <- [(all (== Tails) [x,y],   q*1%1 )] ]  --    return ... all ...
   = [(False,1 % 20),(False,9 % 20),(False,1 % 20),(True,9 % 20)]
```

Of course the one before last line in the derivation above could equally be just written as

```
   = [(all (== Tails) [x,y], q)                                -- ... all ... <$>
              | (x,p) <- [(Heads,   1%2),  (Tails,   1%2 )],   --   fairCoin <*>
                (y,q) <- [(Heads, p*1%10), (Tails, p*9%10)] ]  --   loadedCoin
```

because `(>>= return . f) === fmap f`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the RHS of the `>>=` operator is a lambda expression, **not** the application of `return`:

```
\y -> return (all (== Tails) [x,y])
```

This lambda has type `(Monad m) => a -> m b` as expected.

Let's build up the type from the bottom:

As you say, `all (== Tails) [x,y]` returns `True` or `False`. In otherwords, its type is `Bool`.

Now, checking the type of `return` in ghci, we see that is:

```
Prelude> :t return
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

So `return (all (==Tails) [x,y])` is type `Monad m => m Boolean`.

Wrapping this in a lambda, then gives the type `(Monad m) => a -> m Boolean`.

(Note that somewhere along the way, the compiler will deduce that the concrete monad type is `Prob`.)

You should think of `return` as taking a regular value and wrapping it into a `Monad`.

**Addition:**

Let's analyze the type of

```
flipTwoBind' = coin >>= 
                \x -> loadedCoin   >>= 
                                   \y -> return (all (== Tails) [x,y])
```

We start by noting that the outermost expression here is an application of `(>>=)` which has type:

```
Prelude> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The LHS is `coin` which has type `Prob Coin`, so we immediately deduce that `m` is `Prob` and `a` is `Coin`. This means that the RHS must have type `Coin -> Prob b` for some type `b`. So let's look at the RHS now:

```
\x -> loadedCoin >>= \y -> return (all (== Tails) [x,y])
```

Here we have a lambda that returns the result of an application of `(>>=)`, so the lambda has type

```
(Monad m) => a -> m b
```

This matches the expected type for the application of the first `(>>=)`, so `a` here is `Coin` and `m` is `Prob`.

Now analyzing the inner application of `(>>=)`, we see that its type is deduced to be

```
(>>=) :: Prob Coin -> (Prob -> Prob b) -> Prob b
```

We already analyzed the RHS of the second `(>>=)`, and so `b` is deduced to be `Bool`.

(Note, this may not be the exact order that the compiler uses to deduce the types. It just happens to be the order which my thoughts followed as I analyzed the types for this answer.)

Comment: thanks, Code-Apprentice. Could you please say more as to `Note that somewhere along the way, the compiler will deduce that the concrete monad type is Prob`? I believe that `Prob`'s definition, namely `flatten (fmap f p)` of `>>=` is coming into play, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I'm not entirely sure about those details. My guess is that you will have to analyze the type of the full definition of `flipTwoBind'`. Most likely the deduction will be made from the types of `coin` and `loadedCoin`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I have added a more detailed analysis of the type deduction